# Increase Discount title word limit of 255 character to 500 char on checkout payment page

Tags: magento2.4

In magneto 2.4.6 on checkout page I am applying multiple cart price rule but on summery side bar rule title is cutting after 255 char so can any one help me to know how to increase char limit for discount titles

I have added cart page discount.html code to checkout summery sidebar but same code is working on cart page but not on checkout page

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYo4j.png)
I want to increase limit of discount title words